# SQL Get unique values from select

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am trying to get unique values from a table in oracle via sql. The table looks like this.

Table: ABC with columns name and value.

```
NAME Value
AA   10
B    40
CC   50
AA   70
DD   80
CC   90
EE   100
FF   120
GG   130
H    150
EE   170
I    180
J    200
K    210
L    300
GG   320
```

I want to grab the unique values from ABC for the column name and preferable the ones which have lower value number e.g. AA comes twice so i want to grab AA once but with the one with lower number in value.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (NAME),
    VALUE
FROM
    ABC
ORDER BY
    NAME ASC;
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    NAME       AS NAME  ,
    MIN(VALUE) AS VALUE
FROM ABC
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY NAME ASC;
```

Comment: So basically the same as MSSQL :)

Comment: @Dragos Toader, thanks a lot for your answer, this seems to be work. Can you suggest any good sql book from beginner to expert level. Thanks

Comment: I liked the O'Reilly press Learning SQL http://www.amazon.com/Learning-SQL-Alan-Beaulieu/dp/0596520832/ref=sr_1_8?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1329161802&sr=1-8 For intermediate to advanced, Joe Celko has a lot of good SQL books http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_2_7?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=joe+celko%27s+sql+for+smarties&x=0&y=0&sprefix=Joe+Cel%2Cstripbooks%2C190 For Relational Theory, DB Design, C.J. Date is the father of this whole field.

Comment: @Dragos Toader, thanks again for your response, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the oracle syntax, but is MSSQL a group by (Name) and min on the value would do the trick, along with what you are already doing.